# How do I compute the following integral over a submanifold?

Tags: integration, submanifold

I have the following problem:

> Compute the integral $\int_M f(x)dS(x)$ where $f(x,y)=xy$ and M is the boundary of the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(1,2),(2,1)$.

In the lecture we used the definition of an integral over a manifold to solve such a problem. Therefore I spited up my set M in $$M_1=\{\frac{x}{2}|0\leq x\leq 2\}, M_2=\{-x+3|1\leq x\leq 2\}, M_3=\{2x|0\leq x\leq 1\}$$ Then M is clearly the disjoint union of all this $M_i$'s. Now I defined my 3 charts as follows

1. $M_1$: $\phi_1(x)=(x,\frac{x}{2}),0\leq x\leq 2 $
2. $M_2$: $\phi_2(x)=(x,-x+3), 1\leq x\leq 2$
3. $M_3$: $\phi_3(x)=(x,2x), 0\leq x\leq 1$

Now I used that $$\int_M f(x)dS(x)=\sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{M_i}f(\phi_i(t)\cdot \sqrt{g_{\phi_i} (t)}dt$$ where $g_{\phi_i}(t)$ is the determinant of the gram matrix. But then I somehow get $$g_{\phi_1}=0.75. g_{\phi_2}=0, g_{\phi_3}=-3$$ But this somehow doesn't work.

Could please someone help me finding my error?

It would be nice if we can do it in my way, since this is the only way we had in the lecture and thus the only one we can use at the exam.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It would be helpful to find your error if you posted your calculations for the "gram matrices". Intuitively the $\sqrt{g_{\phi_i}}$ term should be the ratio of the actual length of the line segment vs the length of the domain of the chart. For example $$\sqrt{g_{\phi_2}} = \frac{||(2,1)-(1,2)||}{2-1} = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Secondly, your chart for the first line segment makes no sense because it isn't a line segment at all - it's a hyperbola. And it doesn't connect any of your points.

Comment: So for the gram matrices we always first computed $$D\phi_1=(1,\frac{1}{2}), D\phi_2=(1,-1), D\phi_3=(1,2)$$ then $$G\phi_1=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1&0.5\\0.5&1\end{array}\right), G\phi_2=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1&-1\\-1&1\end{array}\right), G\phi_3=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1&2\\2&1\end{array}\right)$$Then I computed the determinant of all this matrices.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it badly, and corrected my first chart, is it correct now?

Comment: What is a "gram matrix" ? Whatever it is, it probably isn't what you're calculating. And your first chart is now the missing line segment.

Comment: So in the lecture we defined the gram matrix as follows: first we compute $$Df=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}\\...&...\\\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_2}\end{array}\right)$$ then we denote $$v=( \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1},  \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1})$$ and $$w=( \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2},... \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_2})$$

Comment: then the gram matrix is $$G_f=\left( \begin{array}{rrr} \langle v,v\rangle &\langle v,w\rangle \\ \langle w,v\rangle &\langle w,w\rangle\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry what do you mean that the first chart is now the missing line segment?

Comment: Something still isn't adding up. According to that definition for $M_2$ let's say, we have $v=(1,-1)$ and $w=0$

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean. Are my charts all wrong?

Comment: No, I'm saying your definition from your notes makes no sense.

Comment: So you mean the definition of the gram matrix?

Comment: Yes, that definition is for a $2$D manifold, notice the $x_1,x_2$? You have a $1$D manifold. If you insist on doing it this way I cannot help you further.

Comment: how would you do it, so if you would compute the gram matrix in your way, would you get the right result with my definition of the integral over a submanifold? So with this I mean, that probably we can compute the gram determinant in different ways, we only need to use the integration formula over submanifolds I think

Comment: I already told you what I would do in my first comment.

Comment: ah okey and then I would get $$ g_{\phi_1}=5, g_{\phi_2}=2, g_{\phi_3}=5$$ right? and then I can procede as I wanted.

Comment: sorry I mean $\sqrt{g_{phi_1}}=\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}$, $\sqrt{g_{phi_3}}=\sqrt{5}$. Is it correct so?

Comment: if $M$ is a boundary then you have a line integral. Then, what differential form is $dS$ there?

Comment: I don't know it, is it the length of the line?

Answer (score 1):

If $M\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold and $\phi:\Omega\to M$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^k$ a parametrization then the integral of some function $f:M\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $\int_M f=\int_\Omega (f\circ\phi)\cdot \sqrt{\det(D\phi^T D\phi)}$.

In general $D\phi^T D\phi$ is a $k\times k$ matrix. If $k=1$, then $D\phi^T D\phi=[\phi'^T\phi']=[|\phi'|^2]$, which is a $1\times1$ matrix and $\sqrt{\det(D\phi^T D\phi)}=|\phi'|$. This yields the usual formula for the line integral along some curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^n$ : $\int_\gamma f=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\cdot|\gamma'(t)|dt.$

For example the first part of your integral is $\int_{M_1}f(\phi_1(t)\cdot \sqrt{g_{\phi_1} (t)}dt=\int_0^2f(t,\frac t 2)\cdot|(1,\frac 12)|dt=\int_0^2\frac 12 t^2\cdot\frac {\sqrt {5}} {2}dt$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you maybe also look at this question, since you really seems to understand it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318777/how-do-i-compute-this-integral-on-the-set-a