# How do I compute this integral on the set A?

Tags: absolute-value, gaussian-integral

I have the following problem:

> Compute the integral $\int_{\partial A} \langle F,\nu \rangle dS$ where $\nu$ is the normal vector and $$F(x,y,z)=(2x-3y+z,\,\,\,x-y-z,\,\,\,-x+y+2z)$$ and $$A=\{(x,y,z): |x-y|\leq 1, |y-z|\leq 1, |x+z|\leq 1\}$$

Since we have the topic "Gaussian Integral formula" I think that maybe one can compute it with the formula, but to do so, $A$ needs do be compact and have a smooth edge. I don't know how to check this. Otherwise I need to compute it directly, but then I struggle to work with the set $A$. They gave us a hint to use coordinate transformation, but I don't see where.

Could someone please help me?

With the comments from below I tried to solve it again, while solving it I remarked that the were some thinking errors from my side which were hopfully all corrected in the following image, maybe someone can have a look at the image to tell me if this works or if I have more errors.

Thank you very much.

[image: My computations]

Comment: If you assume that your domain $A$ is suitable, do you know how to apply the divergence theorem? To calculate the remaining integral over $A$, the coordinate change $\tilde x=x-y, \tilde y=y-z,\tilde z=x+z$ may help, which also transforms your domain into a more recognizable one.

Comment: Sorry why do I need the divergence theorem? Wouldn‘t it work only with the gaussian formula? Maybe I missinterprete the domain $A$ so if I do a coordinate change then I would get $$A=\{(x‘,y‘,z‘): -1\leq x‘,y‘,z‘ \leq 1\}$$ then if I denote $\phi(x,y,z)=(x‘,y‘,z‘)$ then $|det(\phi)|=|1|=1$. Then we only need to rewrite our function $F$ denoted by $F‘$ with the new coordinates and compute $div(F‘)$ and use the transformation theorem. Is this all correct? So I don‘t see where to use the divergence theorem

Comment: Oh sorry I missundertstood you. I swapt the meaning of the divergence theorem with the convergence theorem. So now it makes more sence. But when I do the substitution isn‘t the domain only a cube with length $2$ so it is conpact and has smooth edge, so I can apply the gaussian Formula?

Comment: Sorry if I bother you again, but I think that I made some errors in the previous commets, therefore I uploaded my computations. Could you maybe tell me if this is correct this was?

Comment: You want to apply the transformation formula to the function $\mathrm{div}F$, so you have to calculate $(\mathrm{div}F)\circ\phi$, but instead you calculated $\mathrm{div}(F\circ\phi)$.

Comment: okey, but $div F=3$ right? so how can I compose this with $\phi$? And the determinant and the rest would work, so the only mistake is the composition of the two functions?

Comment: I looked at it again, I only defined $\phi^{-1}$ explicitly, is it correct that in this case we need the inverse so:$$\phi(x',y',z')=\frac{1}{2} \left(\begin{array}{rrr} x'+y'+z' \\-x'+y'+z'\\-x'-y'+z'\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: If $\mathrm{div} F=3$, then $(\mathrm{div}F)\circ\phi=3$, regardless of what $\phi$ is.

Comment: oh stupid. But now another question. I get two different determinants, so $\frac{1}{\det(D\phi^{-1})}=\frac{1}{2}\neq \frac{1}{8}=\det(\phi)$, what is wrong there because in my opinion I should get the same result

Comment: Well then you found a contradiciton in mathematics and the whole mathematical universe will collapse soon.

Comment: nooooo;) hahah, there must be a huge mistake in my computations, could you maybe show me where, before the whole mathematical universe collaps and all our profs. have to give up their professions

Comment: ...you just miscalculated $\det(D\phi)$, check with your favorite online determinant calculator.

Comment: uhh halleluia we saved the universe thank you, what a stupid error! So at the end I get 12;)

Comment: Seems good to me but no guarantees.

Comment: thank you, no problem, it's only for me so the way is important not the result